# What is the best way to customize Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am now having a lot of troubles with Bootstrap. I used to use it to build a website once and then I have never used it again. But now, I have to use it. I downloaded the compressed version and include JS and CSS file in my project.

Here is the problem. I don't know how to customize it effective. For example, I create a navbar that is much higher (height:90px;) than the bootstrap default navbar. Hence, I have to modify the padding of the navigation panel on the navbar and when the navbar is collapsed, the items in this collapsible navbar are aligned incorrectly due to the padding and margin modification for the large screen.

I have one solution in my mind. May be I have to modify the media query padding and margin or if you have other effective ways to do it. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file with overrides that you load after the bootstrap file. The override file will redefine the bootstrap classes you want to change. It's important that you load the override file after the bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

Just linking Your own CSS file, and insert your custom class to the element. And then styling your custom class & avoid to override default class provided by bootstrap itself. This is my practice when using bootstrap or another CSS Framework.

Never have problem so far. Good luck for your project.